# How to throw an error dialog in a try catch throw?

Tags: java, exception, throw

I'm having a problem with try catch in my code. I can't throw an error dialog. The object alert is red coloured in my IDE and I don't know why.

```
    @FXML
    void textDayWeek(ActionEvent event) {
        String dateBarras = txtDate.getText();
        String[] split = dateBarras.split("/");
        try {
            data = new Data(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[1]), Integer.parseInt(split[2]));
        } catch (MonthInvalidException me) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(split[1]) > 12 || Integer.parseInt(split[1]) < 1)
                throw Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                        alerta.setTitle("error");
            alert.setHeaderText("ERROR");
            alert.setContentText(me);
        }

    }
```

This is the closest i got to solve the problem, but it's still wrong.

Comment: Well, that is not what `throw` is for. You can only throw objects of type `Throwable`. If you just want to show an Alert dialog, you just need to remove the `throw` keyword.

Comment: In the exercise I'm doing it was previously created a class named MonthInvalidException. Why would they create an exception class if I can't use it (and it's supposed to create a JavaFX error dialog)?

Comment: You may wish to make the "throw" when you properly finished up the "alert" object, but i'm not certain how it would work

Comment: @DavidMachado It is hard to jugde without additional context. You seem to miss the basics of [exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html). Methods can throw exceptions to indicate some error occurs. Calling methods can then either handle them using the `catch` clause or propagate them to their caller.